# Blending Modes in LWRP Particles

Tags: unity

I created a particle effect using a material created from **Particles/Simple Lit** shader with an image of white circle tinted red through **Start Color** setting. On the left I have **Alpha Blending Mode** and on the right **Premultiply Blending Mode**.

[image]

Why do I get black lines on the left?

Comment: LWRP = Lightweight Render Pipeline

Comment: What version of Unity are you in?

Comment: Related: https://www.cgdirector.com/premultiplied-alpha-vs-straight-alpha/